# Emacs: invalid byte opcode: op=183, ptr=2 switching window using ace-window

Tags: macos, emacs, macos-sierra

OS: Mac
Fresh install of emacs 25.1
If I run the emacs from the application window and press control x, o to switch window pane, I get this error from ace-window package.

I can run the same package from the emacs terminal with no issues. Any idea what the issue could be?
Here is a screenshot.[image]

Comment: Well, according to bytecomp.el, 178-191 are unused opcodes, so I guess that makes sense.  Try recompiling ace-window.  If you installed a new version of Emacs (replacing an old version), it might be a good idea to reinstall all of your packages, even though bytecode is supposed to be forward compatible.

Comment: when you say recompiling ace-window, How do you recompile ace-window again. Can I just go the init.el file and do a control x control e on the line where ace-windows is? Sorry new to emacs.

Comment: The best way is probably to do `M-x package-delete RET ace-window` and `M-x package-install RET ace-window`.  You can also use `find-library` to find the ace-window.el lisp file and run `M-x byte-recompile-file` in it.

Comment: @jpkotta  I think it worked. You should post that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

@jpkotta comment solved the issue.

Deleted the package and reinstalled it again

```
M-x package-delete RET ace-window 
M-x package-install RET ace-window
```

Thank you again.

Comment: DELETE, REINSTALL package & restart EMACS; Works also for: `invalid byte opcode: op=183, ptr=185` i.e., table not working properly in markdown mode. Tested on ubuntu 16 Emacs 25.

Answer (score 2):

A *solution* to this is to delete all compiled EmacsLisp files in the user's Emacs directory.

```
cd ~/.emacs.d/
find . -name "*.elc" -type f
```

Once you are satisfacted by what the find command returns (it should only return `.elc` files), delete them with the `-delete` option:

```
find . -name "*.elc" -type f -delete
```

Then restart Emacs and they will be regenerated when needed. Easier than to delete and reinstall packages.